# Swift 4 Open Safari with params

Tags: swift, web

I want to write payment with link... i user Safari as default browser with this code:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(payURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

i want to pass params to body:

```
let q1 = URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: "Vladimir")
let q2 = URLQueryItem(name: "email", value: "email@email.com")
let q3 = URLQueryItem(name: "amount", value:  "50")
```

and this to header

**"Content-Type", "application/json/x-www-form-urlencoded"**

**"Accept", "application/json;  charset=utf-8"**

**UPDATED:**

payURL: http://a954032.had.su/api/v1/robokassa/generate-url

method: POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass POST data with openURL method, only GET data. You can use a WebView and a POST request with URLRequest or Alamofire or whatever.